# How to customize the sidepanel of Store Locator plugin from google developer

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use the Store Locator plugin from google developer:
http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/index.html?utm_campaign=sl&utm_source=youtube

I wanted to relocate the search locator to the up of the page-like it is on the google map and this is where I ended up:
1.I created two panels up and side
2. and assigned the same view for both of them.
3. Hide the storelist on the up panel using css.
4. Hiding the search locator on side panel
5. Then while searching on the search locator on the up panel I don get the updated store list and features on the side panel.

Please help me in what I am missing.

Following is the js code I am trying to use:

> google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {   var
>   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
>       center: new google.maps.LatLng(-28, 135),
>       zoom: 5,
>
> ```
> mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP   });
> ```
>
> //var panelDiv = document.getElementById('panel');   var panelDiv =
>   $('.panel');   var searchPanel = $('#searchPanel');
>
> var data = new MedicareDataSource;
>
> var view = new storeLocator.View(map, data, {
>       geolocation: false,
>       features: data.getFeatures()   });
>
> /*var search_panel = new storeLocator.Panel(searchPanel, {
>       view: view,
>       directions: false   });
>   */
>
> var side_panel = new storeLocator.Panel(panelDiv, {
>       view: view,
>       locationSearch: true   });
>
> /*$(search_panel).live('view_changed', function(){
>       alert('Working');
>
> });*/
>
> });

Comment: The plugin link is follows: http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/index.html?utm_campaign=sl&utm_source=youtube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the storelocator.css. this is what I am using now to move the search box on top of the page:

```
.storelocator-panel .location-search {

    top:45px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left:-210px;
    left:50%;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is style

```
<style type="text/css">
  body { font-family: sans-serif; }
  #map-canvas, #panel { height: 500px; }  //HERE
  #panel { width: 300px; float: left; margin-right: 10px; }//HERE
  #panel .feature-filter label { width: 130px; } //HERE
  p.attribution, p.attribution a { color: #666; }
</style>
```

You will need to change this to meet your requirements here is a good [Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) if you need it

Comment: Ok. got the idea. Was already customized using absolute positioning to the doms. Thanks anyway.

Comment: However, Can you please give me any idea how can I customize the left panel - to make the un-ordered list to show as ordered list ? I don wanna make changes within the core plugin,though :-|