# Customizing the panels in Googlemap Store Locator plugin

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-styling

On another thread I was looking for some customization help for the panel from the store locator plugin from Google developer

[How to customize the sidepanel of Store Locator plugin from google developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719036/how-to-customize-the-sidepanel-of-store-locator-plugin-from-google-developer/12730592#12730592)

I need further customization, like :
1. I want to make the Unordered list for the store-list to be ordered.
2. Want to put more info and and details on the list.
3. Want to get the distance for each of the stores from searched location.

Can you please suggest how can I advance ?

Comment: You will get more help if you stop answering your own questions. Unanswered questions attract answers. It will also help if you upvote any helpful answers from others

Comment: Ok. Din know that. Thanks :-| Just thought I might share what I got :S

Answer (score 0):

I think I have got it :
On the DS I am using :

```
store.getInfoPanelItem = function()
    {

      if (!store) {
        return ;
      }
      var details = store.getDetails();

      var html = ['<li class="store"><div class="store"><div class="title">', details.title,
      '</div><div class="address">', details.address, '</div>',
      '<div class="email">', details.email, '</div></div></li>'].join('');

      return $(html)[0];
    }
```

But now when I click on the map point the list item doesn't get selected !!